# Grouping with in minute SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a very typical requirement, I tried to code the group by but isn't working

```
RegDate                    signupdate           channel ID      product 
09/05/2016 23:52:34 09/05/2016 23:55:06 Mobile     1            apple
09/05/2016 23:52:32 09/05/2016 23:52:45 Mobile     2            mango
09/05/2016 23:52:16                     Mobile     3            mango
09/05/2016 23:52:49                     Mobile     4            banana
09/05/2016 23:52:50                     Mobile     5            banana
09/05/2016 23:52:50 09/05/2016 15:52:45 Mobile     5            Kiwi
```

Output

```
Regdate       min     No.of Regs   No.of Signups  channel Product
09/05/2016   23:52      1           1              mobile  apple               
09/05/2016   23:52      2           1              mobile  mango               
09/05/2016   23:52      2                          mobile  banana 
09/05/2016   23:52      1                          mobile  Kiwi
```

My current query:

```
select  SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(regdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'),1,5),count(distinct ID),
       channel, product
from glance_REG_act_Prod_samp
group by SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(regdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'),1,5), source, reg_product
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Using oracle, but the issue here i amnt sure how to include both regdate & signupdate 
select  count(distinct ID),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(regdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'),1,5),
source,reg_product from glance_REG_act_Prod_samp 
group by 
 SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(regdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'),1,5),source,reg_product

Comment: Your output has regdate as first column, but your query has a count first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the date in the `group by`, but not the seconds.  Does this do what you want?

```
select TO_CHAR(regdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), source, reg_product,
       count(distinct ID)
from glance_REG_act_Prod_samp
group by TO_CHAR(regdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), source, reg_product;
```

Note:  You should use `COUNT(*)` unless duplicates of `ID` really exist.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I need both columns as output, no.of regs and no.of signups as stated in output. the query mentioned above only has no.or regs

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:34', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') regdate, to_date('09/05/2016 23:55:06', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') signupdate, 'Mobile' channel, 1 id, 'apple' product from dual union all
                     select to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:32', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') regdate, to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:45', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') signupdate, 'Mobile' channel, 2 id, 'mango' product from dual union all
                     select to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:16', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') regdate, null signupdate, 'Mobile' channel, 3 id, 'mango' product from dual union all
                     select to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:49', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') regdate, null signupdate, 'Mobile' channel, 4 id, 'banana' product from dual union all
                     select to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:50', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') regdate, null signupdate, 'Mobile' channel, 5 id, 'banana' product from dual union all
                     select to_date('09/05/2016 23:52:50', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') regdate, to_date('09/05/2016 15:52:45', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') signupdate, 'Mobile' channel, 6 id, 'kiwi' product from dual)
select   to_char(regdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') regdate,
         to_char(regdate, 'hh24:mi') min,
         count(*) num_of_regs,
         count(case when signupdate >= regdate then 1 end) num_signups,
         channel,
         product
from     sample_data
group by to_char(regdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
         to_char(regdate, 'hh24:mi'),
         channel,
         product
order by product;

REGDATE    MIN   NUM_OF_REGS NUM_SIGNUPS CHANNEL PRODUCT
---------- ----- ----------- ----------- ------- -------
09/05/2016 23:52           1           1 Mobile  apple  
09/05/2016 23:52           2           0 Mobile  banana 
09/05/2016 23:52           1           0 Mobile  kiwi   
09/05/2016 23:52           2           1 Mobile  mango
```

Note that I've assumed that the `id` column is unique and that the fact your last row had id = 5 was a typo.

I have also assumed that the reason why the output for the kiwi product didn't have a signup count available is because the signup date was before the registration date. You didn't explain the logic behind that, so I don't know if that was a typo in your expected output or not. You should be able to amend my query to output whichever results you require, though (for example `case when signupdate is not null then 1 end` perhaps?).

Also, if you want to display blanks instead of 0, that's a simple `CASE` / `DECODE` to change the output to put null instead of 0; your choice.

As a complete aside, you're doing: `SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(regdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'),1,5)` ... why? You're creating a string from the date and then shortening it. Why wouldn't you just create the string from the date in the format you desire? E.g. `to_char(regdate, 'hh24:mi')`

Comment: Hi Boniest,Perfect answer, thanks for the spot on analysis, it worked, your thinking is excellent